# Accessing virtual host remotely

Tags: php, linux, xampp

please I need help and try to understand my question, I have a webserver, xampp set up on and php4.7, I created virtual host and can access them locally, like
app1.localhost
app2.localhost
app3.localhost

but when I try to access remotely with IP address it says server not found, even on a LAN, and when I access the virtual host on the local host with IP address instead of localhost like app1.192.168.0.5 it says server not found

Answer (score 1):

### you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) package

Expose a web server on port 80 of your local machine to the internet

> `ngrok http 80`

Expose a localhost on port **8000** of your local machine to the internet

> `ngrok http http://localhost:8000`

Change `host` and `port` as per your need.

You will get follows result.

```
Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0/2.0
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
Forwarding                    https://92832de0.ngrok.io -> localhost:80

Connnections                  ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Open your allocated address
in your any browser any device.